# string comparison with options crashes in iOS9.1 with iPhone6 only and Xcode7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, xcode7

The method crashes in iOS9.1 worked earlier. It is called from

```
(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
```

The method is

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
{

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.

    for (NSArray *contactsInSection in self.sections)
    {
        for (Contact *contact in contactsInSection)
        {
            NSArray *substringArray = [[contact displayName] componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
            for (NSString *substring in substringArray)
            {
                NSComparisonResult result = [substring compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
                if (result == NSOrderedSame)
                {
                    [self.searchResults addObject:contact];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line that crashes is the line with the comparison: [substring compare:searchText.... ];

The problem occurs in iOS9.1 with iPhone6 device. Works with iPhone5!!!

Here is a screenshot from the compiler

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your range

```
range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
```

is longer than the receiver: `searchText = @"Po"` is 2-character long, while `substring = @"n"` is only 1-character long. Therefore the method will raise an exception:

> *range*:  The range of the receiver over which to perform the comparison. **The range must not exceed the bounds of the receiver.**
>
> > IMPORTANT
> >
> > Raises an NSRangeException if range exceeds the bounds of the receiver.
>
> (ref: [iOS API reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare:options:range:))

Perhaps you should first check `searchText.length <= substring.length`?

Comment: With the length check it worked. However I cannot explain why this thing happens in iPhone6 and it does not happen in iPhone5!